# How to sort a custom list using priority(String) Android

Tags: java, android

I have a list of model class in which there is a variable called priority(String), each item in the list shares 3 common priority (HIGH,LOW,MEDIUM). My question is, I want to sort the list using the its items priority(String). eg. All HIGH priority should move to top, MEDIUM to middle and LOW to last. Thanks in advance.

```
public class Main extends Activity {
    private ArrayList<Model> listOfModel = new ArrayList<>();

    private void setData(){
        listOfModel.addAll(getDataFromServer());
        Collections.sort(listOfModel); //sort using priority 
    }
}

public class Model {
    private String name;
    private String score;
    private String priority;//HIGH,MEDIUM,LOW

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getScore() {
        return score;
    }

    public void setScore(String score) {
        this.score = score;
    }

    public String getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }

    public void setPriority(String priority) {
        this.priority = priority;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_using_comparator.htm You should read about comparators.

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom comparator to sort increasing order of priority i.e. LOW, MEDIUM, HIGH in that order

```
 Collections.sort(listOfModel, new Comparator<Model>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Model m1, Model m2) {
        String p1 = m1.getPriority();
        String p2 = m2.getPriority();
        if(p1 == null) return 1;
        if(p2 == null) return -1; 
        if(p1.equals(p2)) return 0;
        if(p1.equals("LOW") && (p2.equals("MEDIUM") || p2.equals("HIGH")))
            return -1;
        if(p1.equals("MEDIUM") && p2.equals("HIGH"))
            return -1;
        return 1;
    }
 });
```

Comment: There are three priorities, can you please elaborate.

Comment: @SaiKiran Updated. Try now?

Comment: How can i handle null priority i want move it to last

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the below code for sorting custom object**

```
Collections.sort(listOfModel, new Comparator<Model>(){
    public int compare(Model m1, Model m2) {
        return m1.getPriority().compareToIgnoreCase(m2.getPriority());
    }
});
```

Comment: @SaiKiran can you use int instead of string for priority.
I mean HIGH=1, MEDIUM=2, and LOW=3. if yes then You can try this example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
item = "priority";
mSortAttributes(item, listOfModel );

public void mSortAttributes(final String item, ArrayList<Model> sortList ){
        Collections.sort(sortList, new Comparator<Model>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Model lhs, Model rhs) {
                int retVal = 0;
                //Ascending Order
                if (item.equals("name")) {
                    retVal = lhs.name.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.name);
                } else if (item.equals(" score")) {
                    retVal = lhs.score.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.score);
                } else if (item.equals("priority")) {
                    retVal = lhs.priority.compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.priority);
                } 
                return retVal;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This Code.this is working fine

```
static class myComparater implements Comparator<Model> {

        @Override
        public int compare(Model o1, Model o2) {
            String p1 = o1.getPriority();
            String p2 = o2.getPriority();
            if (p1.equals(p2)) {
                return 0;
            }
            if (p1.equals("HIGH") && (p2.equals("MEDIUM") || p2.equals("LOW"))) {
                return -1;
            }
            if (p1.equals("MEDIUM") && p2.equals("LOW")) {
                return -1;
            }
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working. Using this code you can add more case.

```
private static Comparator<OrderHistoryItemData> COMPARE_BY_PAYMENT = new Comparator<OrderHistoryItemData>() {
    private int map(String str) {
        switch (str) {
            case "HIGH":
                return 0;
            case "MEDIUM":
                return 1;
            case "LOW":
                return 2;
            default:
                return 3;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        return map(o1) - map(o2 );
    }
};
```